# When i am trying to create a jira ticket by choosing components as multiselect i am getting Error for field components: data was not an array

Tags: jira

For a jira issue fields, i have configured components field type as multi select and used it to create ticket using postman i am getting below error

> Error for field components: data was not an array

This is for specific user credentials, and also it is working for different credentials

Comment: Sounds like a problem with permissions. But I think this question is better asked at the [atlassian community](https://community.atlassian.com/)

Comment: Can you share your JSON that you use on Postman?